# How is Grouping Columns and aggregation works in Spark Java API?

Tags: java, apache-spark, group-by, dataset, aggregate

I am doing this following Operation to Dataset

```
dataset
.select(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("expend1"),col("expend2"))
.groupBy(col("col1"),col("col2"))
.agg(sum(col("expend1")),sum(col("expend2")));
```

I am not sure the syntax is right? But as of now the Dataset when writing to csv will have below data's

```
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 | col1  | col2  |expend1|expend1|
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 |itemA1 | itemA2|    4  |  5    |
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 |itemA1 | itemA2|    4  |  5    |
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 |itemA1 | itemA2|    2  |  1    |
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 |itemB1 | itemB2|    6  |  3    |
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 |itemB1 | itemB2|    3  |  4    |
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

But my expected results should be as below

```
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 | col1  | col2  |expend1|expend1|
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 |itemA1 | itemA2|   10  |  11   |
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
 |itemB1 | itemB2|    9  |   7   |
 +-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How can I modify the code?
I am using JAVAsparkAPI to the above Operations. and writing them to csv as

```
dataset.coalesce(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header",true).csv(folderpath);
```

For eg:

```
Dataset <Row> sampleDS= spark.table("table");
sampleDS=sampleDS
.filter("*applying filter*");

sampleDS=sampleDS
.select(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("expend1")col("expend2"))
.groupBy(col("col1"))
.agg(sum(col("expend1")),sum(col("expend2")))
.sort(col("col1"),col("col2"));
```

This is what I am trying to do for the above expect results.

**The Working Solution**

The below changes worked for me :

```
sampleDS=sampleDS
    .select(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("expend1")col("expend2"))
    .groupBy(col("col1"))
    .agg(expr("sum(expend1)").as("expend1"),expr("sum(expend2)").as("expend2"))
    .sort(col("col1"),col("col2"));
```

Comment: How are you writing to csv? what is the result of `dataset.groupBy.agg().show()`

Comment: The closing parenthesis for the first agg sum is not present. You have `.agg(sum(col("expend1"),sum(col("expend2")))` and you probably want `.agg(sum(col("expend1")),sum(col("expend2")))`

Comment: @Jeremy I might have missed here but its there.

Comment: @philantrovert Yes I have updated the writing of CSV part. But the result has same cols with wrong data. NO idea How its grouping . and moreover there's dup cols, I am not sure of the syntax too

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a [mcve] (especially example input in a format that can be directly used) and version details.

Comment: @user6910411 updated a sample what I am trying to do.

Comment: The logic of your code is right. It should be working. It seems like you may have forgotten to assign the result of the groupBy to a variable and that you write the original dataset instead. The only way to know what's wrong is if you provide all the code (read, tranform and write)

Comment: I assume `dataset` is your original DataFrame. You are doing transformations on it which is correct, but then you are using `dataset.coalesce(1).write....`. Since DataFrames are immutable, `dataset` will still contain the original data. Could that be the case?

Comment: @philantrovert Nothing wrong with `coalesce(1)` I think that shud not be any problem for writing the correct data.

Comment: @Oli This is it the Code. my `table` I am reading is nothing but parque files. which reading as expected . But the GRoup by is not working.

Comment: How are you reassigning the dataframe again to `sampleDS`? Your example is not really a [mcve].

Comment: @philantrovert can you say me how do you group by data’s in sparkAPI using JAVA. I would really allreciate your help.